# Get quantity for documents in a Project out of the SolidWorks SQL database

Tags: solidworks

I'm trying to pull all of the documents in a project and the quantity used that we have listed in SolidWorks. I believe I pulled the documents list correctly, but I'm not finding any fields or tables related to the quantity.

The query below pulled the documents, but I need to add the quantity:

```
select 
p2.path [Child Path], 
d.filename [Child Filename], 
LEFT(d.filename,CHARINDEX('.',d.filename)-1) as 'Child Part',
RIGHT(d.filename,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(d.filename))-1) as 'Child File Type',
p2.path [Parent Path], 
par.filename [Parent Filename],
LEFT(par.filename,CHARINDEX('.',par.filename)-1) as 'Child Part',
RIGHT(par.filename,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(par.filename))-1) as 'Child File Type'

from documents d
inner join xrefs x on x.xrefdocument = d.documentid and x.xrefrevnr = d.latestrevisionno
inner join documents par on par.documentid = x.documentid and par.latestrevisionno = x.revnr
inner join documentsinprojects dp1 on dp1.documentid = par.documentid
inner join documentsinprojects dp2 on dp2.documentid = d.documentid
inner join projects p1 on p1.projectid = dp1.projectid
inner join projects p2 on p2.projectid = dp2.projectid
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this by referencing an active BOM.  Check out the TABLE BomSheetValue.